# How to get the month name in English using Numbers?

Tags: macos, numbers

I'm using Apple Numbers v 3.6.1 on OS X 10.11 to automatically fill all the info I need to generate a receipt each month.

```
"... " & MONTHNAME(MONTH(TODAY())) & " 1 − " & MONTHNAME(MONTH(TODAY())) & " " & DAY(EOMONTH(TODAY();0))&", " & YEAR(NOW())
```

It should print:

```
... December 1 − December 31, 2015
```

But I can only get the localized name of month (Italian) instead of the English one.

How can I ask Numbers to give me the English name of the month?

Comment: I've assumed you are using numbers on OS X - please edit this if my guesses were incorrect...

Comment: yes it's right, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing the localization language in your system, you could do something like this:

- Create a table in a separate tab and Lock/hide it later
- Then, in English add the month names in order from January to December in one column.  (A1-A12) [Be sure to set the cells as Text so that they don't show the localized names]
- Change your formula to refer to the correct month name based on the month number.  Lots of nested `IF()`'s but if the `MONTH(TODAY)` is placed in a cell in the utility table, that will make the formula a bit more manageable.
  *Thanks to the OP for suggesting it in the comments!*
- place this formula in a cell then reference that cell in your original formula

Of course you can hard code the month names in the formulas, but then you would have to redo it in each instance if you changed languages.  This way you can just change the text in the reference table without breaking your formula.  Also, if you need the month name elsewhere, there is no need to re-enter the formula, just refer to the cell containing it.

[image: Formula to hard code month names]

[image: Original formula]

---

### EDIT

A simpler formula (takes getting used to, though) is to use `INDEX(MATCH())`

I actually use this method in a expense sheet I keep for English and French.

- First I create a table with the numbers for each month and then text for each month in the target language.
- Get the date
- Use `INDEX ( MonthTextLang, MATCH ( MonthNumber, NumberColumn ))`

`INDEX ( "English", MATCH ( MONTH ( TODAY )), NumberColumn ))`

[image: English]

[image: French]

Comment: About the variables, couldn't be enough to put the `MONTH(TODAY())` inside a cell and refer to that cell in the formula?

Comment: Good idea! That would simplify the formula even more.

Comment: I just can't leave well enough alone.  LOL

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct [words](http://www.apple.com/mac/numbers/compatibility/functions.html) in your script. Make sure that you have all of your OS X settings on English (US).